# Plotting a graph given function definition

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to plot a graph of iterations of a certain function in python. I have defined the function as stated below but I am unsure on how to plot the graph such that the y value is on the y axis and the iteration number is on the x axis.

So, I have tried using the `plt.plot` function with different values in as my x values but using `logistic(4, 0.7)` as the y value for the y axis.

```
def logistic(A, x):
    y = A * x * (1 - x)
    return y
```

But each return an error. Can anyone shed any light on this, I want to do a total of 1000 iterations.

Comment: You might want to show the error you are getting. Please look [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), Make sure we are able to give all the code that will allow us to reproduce the error so that we can actually help you. Also wrong indentation in the code

Comment: What do you mean by "a total of 1000 iterations"? What's an iteration? What's range should the x axis have?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand much what you are saying concerning x being number ofiteration while you are showing us function **logistic(4, 0.7)**. As far as I know, iterations is integer, whole number. You cant iterate just halfly or partially

```
def logistic(A, x):
    y = A * x * (1 - x)
    return y

A = 1

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

for x in range(1,1000):
    x_vals.append(x)
    y_vals.append(logistic(A,x))
    #plt.plot(x_vals,y_vals) # See every iteration
    #plt.show()
plt.plot(x_vals,y_vals) # See all iterations at once
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the logistic map. Are you trying to make a cobweb plot? If so, your error may be elsewhere. As others have mentioned, you should post the error message and your code, so we can better help you. However, based on what you've given us, you can use `numpy.arrays` to achieve your desired result.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start = 0
end = 1
num = 1000

# Create array of 'num' evenly spaced values between 'start' and 'end'
x = np.linspace(start, end, num)

# Initialize y array
y = np.zeros(len(x))

# Logistic function
def logistic(A, x):
    y = A * x * (1 - x)
    return y

# Add values to y array
for i in range(len(x)):
    y[i] = logistic(4, x[i])

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

However, with `numpy.arrays`, you can omit the `for` loop and just do

```
x = np.linspace(start, end, num)
y = logistic(4, x)
```

and you'll get the same result, but faster.